# Bootstrap table images as border

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap class *"table"* and I want replace default borders with an image. With Bootstrap selectors I'm able to hide default borders and show new borders ([live preview](https://jsfiddle.net/nr62e6ys/)). When I try to add border-image, it doesn't appear ([live preview 2](https://jsfiddle.net/nr62e6ys/1/)).

What I tryied and it didn't help:

- border-width
- border-height
- border: 5px solid transparent; border-image
- border-top: 1px;
- Playing with !imporant

Code of table, where image is not showing:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="16,666%">First</th>
      <th width="33,333%">Second</th>
      <th width="16,666%">Third</th>
      <th width="16,666%">Fourth</th>
      <th width="16,666%">Fifth</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>Ipsum</td>
      <td>Dolor</td>
      <td>Sit</td>
      <td>Amet</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>Ipsum</td>
      <td>Dolor</td>
      <td>Sit</td>
      <td>Amet</td>
   </tr>
 <tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.table > thead > tr > th,
.table > tbody > tr > th,
.table > tfoot > tr > th,
.table > thead > tr > td,
.table > tbody > tr > td,
.table > tfoot > tr > td {
  border: none;
  border-image: url('http://s24.postimg.org/4j8lmprz9/border.png') !important;
}

.table > thead > tr > th {
  border: none;
  border-image: url('http://s24.postimg.org/4j8lmprz9/border.png') !important;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried reading any [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)? How do you expect it to show when you set the `border-width` `0` with `border:none`? It's the same as setting width or height to `0` for an `<img>`. Both `border` and `border-image` are shorthand properties, setting [`3`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border.asp), respectively [`5`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp) other properties.

Comment: **[`This link`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp)** might be helpful.. Replace your `url`  in the **Try it** section given there and see the border replaced by image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `border-image` to a `div` element but not with `table`, you can add some padding to the main `.table` class and apply the `background-image` into it.

You can update your CSS as:

```
.table{
  border-spacing: 4px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  background-image: url('http://s24.postimg.org/4j8lmprz9/border.png');
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
.table > thead > tr > th,
.table > tbody > tr > th,
.table > tfoot > tr > th,
.table > thead > tr > td,
.table > tbody > tr > td,
.table > tfoot > tr > td {
  border: none;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.table > thead > tr > th {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8tjsq0gz/

Comment: Finally made based on your code. Thank.

[Live preview with answer](https://jsfiddle.net/nr62e6ys/4/)